# Basic Ruby class - correct code so it returns expected value

Tags: ruby

Extremely basic, yet I can't figure it out! Noob issues - I have tried several different answers for this, and I am still getting argument errors. Can someone please help enlighten me on the correct answer?

Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you include the error also. You should not get *Argument error*, rather *local variable or method not found error* as per the current context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end
```

You need to access your instance variables by prefixing the variable name with `@`. Just the same way as when you assigned it.

Answer (score 4):

`name` is not available in `greet`. You can either use `@name`, or add an [accessor](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html):

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end
```

or

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def greet(other_name)
    "Hi #{other_name}, my name is #{name}"
  end
end
```